# Integrate Omnipay with Aimeos E-commerce

Tags: php, laravel, omnipay

I'm using Aimeos Ecommerce package and I want to have an integrated payment for purchasing with credit cards. and I want to use omnipay. my required composer.json array is as follows:

```
"require": {
"php": "^7.2",
"aimeos/aimeos-laravel": "~2019.10",
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
"laravel/framework": "^6.0",
"laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
"laravel/ui": "^1.2",
"aimeos/ai-payments": "dev-master",
"league/omnipay": "3",
"omnipay/paypal": "^3.0"
},
```

when I execute [ composer require omnipay/common:^3 ] in CMD in gives ma this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Can only install one of: aimeos/aimeos-core[dev-master, 2019.10.17].
- Can only install one of: aimeos/aimeos-core[dev-master, 2019.10.17].
- Can only install one of: aimeos/aimeos-core[dev-master, 2019.10.17].
- aimeos/ai-payments dev-master requires aimeos/aimeos-core dev-master -> satisfiable >by aimeos/aimeos-core[dev-master].
 -Installation request for aimeos/ai-payments dev-master -> satisfiable by aimeos/ai->payments[dev-master].
 -Installation request for aimeos/aimeos-core (locked at 2019.10.17) -> satisfiable  by aimeos/aimeos-core[2019.10.17].
  Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

But nothing shows on the service page [ payment option ] even the paypal. How do I enable Credit Card payment.

Comment: Try running > composer require aimeos/aimeos-core before composer require omnipay/common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: you want to use the branch `dev-master` for the package `aimeos/ai-payments`, and this requires the branch `dev-master` for `aimeos/aimeos-core`. Additionally, you want to use a **stable** branch for the package `aimeos/aimeos-laravel`, and this also requires a **stable** branch for the package `aimeos/aimeos-core`.

As long as you have no explicit need to require a unstable branch, you should simply use the same version requirement `~2019.10` for `aimeos/ai-payments`